# Directshow, format type change filter

Tags: directshow, lazarus, dspack

How can I change `rcTarget` in a `filter`?

[Source and Target Rectangles in Video Renderers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377618(v=vs.85).aspx)

I want, example in free pascal and DSpack.
My project  is to work with `720x576` video format. If I can change a filter `rcTarget` ex .: `LAVSplitter` pin VIDEO, I solved my problems.

---

I want to explain my problem:

My project and developed with DSPack and lazarus.
I have to run a media file playlist and add text scrolling.
Output DeckLink card analog or similar. For connect TV monitor means
S-Video.

Now I see in the videowindow desktop and TV monitors connected to DeckLink, only original videos 720x576.

I want all video formats run. msdn site : 
[Source and Target Rectangles in Video Renderers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377618(v=vs.85).aspx)
describes how to change rcTarget in videoinfoheader. I do not know how to write in pascal, used dspack. or is there another way to resize video?
I have to build a new filter or I can change properties in rcTarget filter example: LAVSplitter?

my graph
| sourcefile| -> 1920x1080 | LAV Splitter | -> 720x576 | LAV Decoder| -> Tee Filter| -> videowindows  and DeckLink render

On the internet many examples to resize external device capture webcam, 
i do not find example code external device output.
For this I ask for help.

I have an example for MPEG-2, not working. Where I go wrong?

```
// var
//    mt     : AM_Media_Type;
//    seqHdr : array [0..0] of byte;  //this is right?
//    pWIH   : MPEG2VIDEOINFO;
ZeroMemory(@Mt, sizeof(AM_MEDIA_TYPE));
Mt.MajorType := MEDIATYPE_Video;
Mt.SubType := MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB32;
Mt.FormatType := FORMAT_MPEG2_VIDEO;

Mt.cbFormat := sizeof(MPEG2VIDEOINFO) + sizeof(seqHdr); 
mt.pbFormat := CoTaskMemAlloc(mt.cbFormat);

if (mt.pbFormat = NULL) then exit;  //   ERROR 
ZeroMemory(mt.pbFormat, mt.cbFormat);

{ RCSRC.Left := 0;
RCSRC.Top:= 0;
RCSRC.Right := 0;
RCSRC.Bottom := 0;
}
pWIH.hdr.rcSource.Left:=0;    
pWIH.hdr.rcSource.Top:=0;
pWIH.hdr.rcSource.Right:=0;
pWIH.hdr.rcSource.Bottom:=0;
// pWIH.hdr.rcSource := RCSRC;
//  pWIH.hdr.rcTarget := Rect(0,0,720,576);
pWIH.hdr.rcTarget.Left:=0;
pWIH.hdr.rcTarget.Top:=0;
pWIH.hdr.rcTarget.Right:=576;
pWIH.hdr.rcTarget.Bottom:=720;
pWIH.hdr.AvgTimePerFrame := 278335;
pWIH.hdr.dwPictAspectRatioX := 4;
pWIH.hdr.dwPictAspectRatioY := 3;
pWIH.hdr.bmiHeader.biSize := 40;
pWIH.hdr.bmiHeader.biWidth := 720;
pWIH.hdr.bmiHeader.biHeight := 576;
pWIH.cbSequenceHeader := sizeof(seqHdr);
 CopyMemory(@pwih.dwSequenceHeader, @seqHdr, sizeof(seqhdr));
//-------------------------------------
SourceFilter.FindPin('Output',PinOutSource);
(VideoWindow1 as IBaseFilter).FindPin('Input',PIn_input);
PinOutSource.Connect(PIn_input,@mt);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant understand what you try to achieve. Do you want to resize the video frames after they come out from LAV Video Decoder?

Comment: Yes, i want to resize the video.
I have to create a structure media type (mt: AM_Media_Type;)
and assign mt in pin out. Maybe in LAVSplitter or LAV Video Decoder or other filter upstream of the graph.
you can help to build this?
perhaps with this?
out_pin.ConnectionMediaType(mt)
how to write media type?

Answer (score 0):

thank you, thank you,thank you.
I want to use ( 3.Use this Resizer DMO filter ). 
I created Resize filter, as your example. OK. 
Now I want to use: **(FResizerDMO as IMediaObject).SetOutputType** for resize my video. 
I have difficulty, you can help me?

in site alax.info :

1. CoCreateInstance the DSP as DMO and add it to DMO Wrapper Filter
2. Use IWMResizerProps::SetFullCropRegion to initialize the DSP **// I do not have to crop region?**
3. Connect input pin
4. Set output type via IMediaObject::SetOutputType
5. IGraphBuilder::ConnectDirect output pin

This above is correct?

I write this:

```
var pVIH :VIDEOINFOHEADER; mt :DMO_MEDIA_TYPE;
ZeroMemory(@mt, sizeof(DMO_MEDIA_TYPE));
mt.majortype := MEDIATYPE_Video;
mt.subtype := MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB32;
mt.formattype := FORMAT_VideoInfo;
//    ** I can not translate this **
//    VIDEOINFOHEADER * pVIH = (VIDEOINFOHEADER *)pmt->pbFormat;
//    pVIH := TVideoInfoHeader(mt.pbFormat^);   ????
pVIH.bmiHeader.biWidth := 720;
pVIH.bmiHeader.biHeight := 576;
pVIH.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter:=9;
pVIH.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter:=16;
pVIH.bmiHeader.biSizeImage := 720 * 480 * 3;
hr := (FResizerDMO as IMediaObject).SetOutputType(0,@mt,DMO_SET_TYPEF_CLEAR);
   if hr <> S_OK then showmessage('error'); // I receive error
```

correct this road?
if it is correct you can help because it does not work.

Comment: You translate it correct. I have used this DMO only with my own wrapper filter, and not with the standard one, so I dont know if I can help on this. What is the error code (hr) returned by SetOutputType and ConnectDirect?

Comment: 1) I receive in hr  ( DMO_E_TYPE_NOT_ACCEPTED ). 2) I understand that I have to initialize :  IWMResizerProps::SetFullCropRegion to initialize the DSP, I do not know how to do, help.

Comment: First of, you need to specify mt.lSampleSize - it the same as the bitmap size. biSizeImage is wrong. RGB32 is 4 byte per pixel and you calculate with 3. You should also specify bmiHeader.biSize := SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader) and first nullify the whole pVIH with FillChar(pVih^, SizeOf(TVideoInfoHeader), 0); (after pVih := TVideoInfoHeader(pbFormat...))

Comment: 1) mt.lSampleSize := pVIH.bmiHeader.biSizeImage; 2) FillChar(pVIH, SizeOf(TVideoInfoHeader), 0); if I use : FillChar(pVIH^,... receive error compiler. 3) pVIH := TVideoInfoHeader(mt.pbFormat^); I receive error in run : External SIGSEGV 4) pVIH.bmiHeader.biSizeImage := 720 * 576 * 4;

Comment: 3) if I insert : mt.pbFormat := CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(VIDEOINFOHEADER)); and next  pVIH := TVideoInfoHeader(mt.pbFormat^); I have no runtime error.  In SetOutputType i receive in hr ( DMO_E_TYPE_NOT_ACCEPTED ).

Comment: You should ask this as a different question, Something like "How to work with AMMediaType for video filters".

Comment: thank you. I write this Ask Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386190/how-to-work-with-ammediatype-for-video-filters

Comment: in the site forum msdn:  their  responded:I don't think your code around pbFormat is correct. Apparently, FillChar is to cause memory access vioaltion as you do it too early. Then it looks like you're modifying a copy of allocated data (pVIH declaration is not shown). Then biXPelsPerMeter/biYPelsPerMeter looks somewhat weird even though I think this can be accepted. Then you don't initilaize the rest of TVideoInfoHeader fields. Just watch pVIH in debuger before the call and you will see the structure is not well-defined.